# How can I apply a style using LESS to a nephew element of a class

Tags: html, css, less

I have these elements on the HTML:

```
 <div id="td-status" class="icongb-cancelled"></div>
 <div class="ticket-header-text">
     <span class="bet-text">TEXT1</span>
     <span>TEXT2</span>
  </div>
```

and I want to apply a certain style using LESS to TEXT1 ('bet-text' class) whether its uncle has a cercaion class (in this case icongb-cancelled). I'd like to apply it also to TEXT2 (no class). Would it be possible?

I'm using this code, but it doesn't work:

```
 .icongb_cancelled ~ .ticket-header-text {
     & .bet-text {
         color: #959595;
     }
 }
```

NOTE: I don't want to use JQuery to add or remove any class.
I want to make it just using LESS wihtout any modifying on the HTML.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The code was fine, the problem was that I was using an underscore instead of a dash. so you can use that code to apply a style to a nephew element.

Comment: I think you have some terms mixed up... I get your meaning but divs aren't brothers to one another, siblings sure- but only when they share a class (or when generic elements are used). That aside, to **my** knowledge this isn't possible

Comment: Also, if you want to target only the .ticket-header-text adjacent to .icongb_cancelled, use + instead of ~

Comment: Can you please check in the parsed CSS what your selector looks like? Have you parsed the LESS file, to re-generate the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.icongb_canceled` in the selector, but the class is `icongb-canceled`.
**Dash** vs **underscore**. They need to match.

Comment: The problem was the dash and the underscore. I'm grateful for your answer, it solved my problem. I didn't see it as an useful question with that error, so I updated it to make it useful for other people. I had to add a Note but too much work :) Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Lorenzo, in that case you have two options: **a)** revert the change, because right now the question doesn't make sense (there's no reason for the described behavior to be happening in the posted code - and therefore it's less useful than when containing the error; in current form it would only add confusion to anyone with a similar problem) and mark my answer as correct (it addressed the cause of the problem and provided correct solution) or **b)** consider the question a "*typo*", therefore off-topic on [SO], therefore not useful to future users, and delete it altogether.

Comment: Note the second reason in rules regarding [editing other people's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit): "*to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it*". Same applies to modifying own questions: edits should remove ambiguity, add context, or correct mistakes (in formulating the question) **without changing its meaning**. Modifying the question to include the answer goes against general principles of [so] and is definitely counter productive (it undermines the question's ability to help others).

Comment: Closing the question as off topic -> typo would be the best solution. If the whole thing works as-is after fixing the typo, there is no use for others, and it may only confuse people who are looking for a solution for their incorrect CSS or LESS selectors.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I'm torn on this one, in terms of usefulness. From a professional coder's perspective, it's definitely an *typo*. But most beginners do not always fully understand the importance of a single character (sometimes even invisible ones) for parsers and it's definitely a common mistake. So I wouldn't dismiss the questions' potential to be helpful for others, as long as the *typo* is underlined - it basically tells future users: triple-check for typos - and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `.icongb-cancelled ~ .ticket-header-text .bet-text`, which is valid in CSS, but also is LESS compatible:

```css
.icongb-cancelled ~ .ticket-header-text .bet-text {
  color: blue;
}

.icongb-cancelled ~ .ticket-header-text span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="td-status" class="icongb-cancelled"></div>
 <div class="ticket-header-text">
     <span class="bet-text">TEXT1</span>
     <span>TEXT2</span>
  </div>
```